# How to configure Id property of Restangular URL building

Tags: ajax, angularjs, httprequest, restangular

**Let**,

```
Restangular.one('users').getList().then(function(users) {
  $scope.user = users[0]; 
});
```

---

**Another GET request:**

Let:    `user: { id: '123' }`

`$scope.cars = $scope.user.getList('cars');`   This would fires a GET request: /users/**123**/cars

where the **123** is gotten from the *id property*.

---

**Question:**

Is it possible to explicitely configure if my object's *id property*, for example: was named **username**.

```
user: { username: '123' }
```

Comment: It seems it is pretty trivial, just take a look at the doc https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better answer would be to set the id field of a particular service.

```
angular.module('app')
   .service('SomeService', ['rootUrl', 'Restangular', function SomeService(rootUrl, Restangular) {
     return Restangular.withConfig(function (config) {
     config.setRestangularFields({"id": "username"});
   }).all('cars');
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it for ALL objects, but not for just one object at the moment. Only option I can think of is just setting in the `addElementTransformer` user.id = user.username and it'll work.